# Тире после "чаще"

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Такое бывает весной, чаще()осенью...

Ставится ли здесь тире?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тире не требуется. А тире как авторский знак можно впихнуть почти куда угодно, но это относится к художественному тексту и этим не стоит злоупотреблять.

Фраза довольно корявая. Лучше так:

*Такое бывает весной, но чаще осенью.
Такое бывает весной, а чаще осенью.*

Кстати, здесь и тире было бы более оправданным.